# How to update a static html website hosted on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have hosted a static HTML website hosted on aws s3 using the Udemy video tutorial [Amazon Web Services (AWS) Certified 2018 - 4 Certifications](https://www.udemy.com/aws-certified-associate-architect-developer-sysops-admin/).

I have successfully hosted the website, however when I attempted to update the site by changing the some text in the `index.html` file and then uploading the new `index.html` to S3, I do not see my updates. Rather, I see the original webpage content. Occasionally, I am able to refresh the page or close my Chrome browser in order to see my changes, however it is not stable. Please help!

Comment: You tagged your question with [amazon-cloudfront] but didn't mention it anywhere in your question. If you are using CloudFront as a CDN then that is most likely where the caching is happening.

Comment: ...and you would need to invalidate that cache entry.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like your browser is caching the content.

If you open a different browser (eg Firefox) and the content has updated, then everything is fine on S3. It's just a matter of clearing your browser cache or waiting for the cached content to expire.

Comment: Thanks for the response. About how long would it take to expire? I've found other posts referring to reducing the TTL or invalidating content to hasten content update. Would you recommend those methods or patiently waiting for the cached content to expire?

Comment: It can be configured. As default Cloudfront will cache content for 86400 seconds (1 day). If you are doing something like continuous deployment it is better you adjust the TTL to your deployment cycle. If you are not normally making a lot of deployments in one day, you can invalidate the cache only when is crucial. Keep in mind that cache invalidation will cost you money.